# Need for a powershell script to read from variable text not the name of the variable

Tags: windows, powershell, variables, text

I need a script to pull data from another. Here's what I have:

```
$myvar = (cat "C:\ProgramData\CrashPlan\log\app.log" | Select-String -pattern "<path include=")
$v = $myvar -replace '.*='
$vv = $v -replace '/>'
$first = $vv | select-object -first 1
$second = $vv | select-object -skip 1 | select-object -first 1
$third = $vv | select-object -skip 2 | select-object -first 1
$fourth = $vv | select-object -skip 3 | select-object -first 1
$fifth = $vv | select-object -skip 4 | select-object -first 1

cd "C:\pcheck\CheckPermissions"
.\CheckPermissions.ps1 $first
```

When I run the above, I get "directory not found" even after I verify the output of $first is "E:\" Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: That error comes from `CheckPermissions.ps1`?  You'll probably need to provide that script, too, to see where the problem is.

Comment: No, the is caused when I call that script in the provided script. For some reason when I dot source checkpermissions.ps1, it doesn't recognize the output of $first. I'm assuming that it's taking the variable at face value rather than the output, which should be "E:\"

Comment: The line `.\CheckPermissions.ps1 $first` throws that error?  Or `cd "C:\pcheck\CheckPermissions"`?  Or...?

Comment: .\CheckPermissions.ps1 $first outputs the error. $first = "E:\" and running  .\CheckPermissions.ps1 "E:\" works correctly. Sorry, on phone. Having ING trouble with formatting.

Comment: @pilvlp - PLEASE add the full text of the error to your QUESTION, not to the replies/comments.

Comment: @lee_daily1 It has been there since I posted. "Directory not found".

Comment: @pilvlp - that is not what i see in my error display when PoSh can't find a directory. instead, i get something that starts with `Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\NotThere' because it does not exist.` and then goes on to list the line of code that triggered the error. so ... what is giving you that error?

Comment: @lee_daily I'll have to wait until I get back home to give you further information. Should be at some point tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The error is with the following line:

.\CheckPermissions.ps1 $first

$first = "E:\" but the return on that line comes back as "directory not found" I have confirmed $first output and the .\CheckPermissions.ps1 "E:\" works on their own. My thought is that the script is literally running the variable name rather than the variable output.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Basically, I need to pass the variables($first, $second, etc.) from the OP script to .\CheckPermissions.ps1

Comment: @pilvlp - as others have mentioned, the content of the file that is triggering the error is REQUIRED. also, as i mentioned, the error you have listed IS NOT A STANDARD POWERSHELL ERROR. i'm shouting that  since you have apparently not noticed the previous mention of that fact. **_where is the error ACTUALLY coming from?_**

Comment: Without showing the `CheckPermissions` script, there is no way of telling what causes the error. The script may not expect a string `"E:\"`, but just the driveletter `"E"` or maybe there are invisible characters surrounding the string in $first..

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured it out. 

`CheckPermissions.ps1` was either 1. Not able to translate the variables in my script or 2. Not able to read the variables because they aren't using a file path. I copied my code directly to `CheckPermissions.ps1` and I received the same output.

Another technician actually automated this using functions. I sincerely appreciate your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Select-string returns an object with many properties.  I think you want the line property.

```
$myvar = (cat "C:\ProgramData\CrashPlan\log\app.log" | 
  Select-String -pattern "<path include=").line
```

Comment: This was my first thought, too, but once you pass a `MatchInfo` to `-replace` you get back a plain `String`.

Comment: @BACON oh yeah it has a .tostring()